# gitlab is inaccessible from browser

Tags: gitlab

After sudden restart of server, gitlab is inaccessible. I don't know whats happen. I have posted another question as well [check this here](https://superuser.com/questions/743970/error-in-gitlab-git-configured-for-git-user-no-try-fixing-it). Gitlab is up and running when I start/restart from server but it is inaccessible from browser(This is way I used to access `GtiLab`).

When I start `GitLab`

```
The GitLab Unicorn web server with pid 2020 is running
The GitLab SideKiq job dispatcher with pid 2028 is running
GitLab and all its components are up and running.
```

but I can't access the web interface of gitlab by using IP of Git container: 192.168.2.9. I can able to ping 192.168.2.9 from my system.

Comment: sorry guys it was my problem I didn't check ngnix server, it wasn't running. That was the problem. I changed the IP address of server two weeks before but at that time I didn't get ngnix server running error. I don't know why I get this error now after long time. Now I changed the Ip address in nginx server and every think working fine.

Answer (score 1):

That you can ping 192.168.2.9 does nothing to do with GitLab page not showing up. First of all, it would we helpful if you could paste the output of this commands:

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
```

You can also check **GitLab's & nginx's logs** for errors and that you configured well **GitLab's page on nginx**.

If you keep finding troubles I recommend you to Install the lates **Omnibus** version at: https://www.gitlab.com/downloads/ which will install you the latest GitLab stable version and all it's dependencies, so you don't have to do a manual installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after the restart of the machine. It turned out that I had installed a firewall that was re-enabled at startup, so the connection would be refused. I disabled it and all worked fine afterwards.